# Binance Smart Chain TestNet contract deployment JSON RPC error execution Reverted

Tags: blockchain, smartcontracts, binance-smart-chain

I have delopyed the MasterChef.sol smart contract at the address 0x852741C58ca084154201691CeB5B9D3312415C18 on the Bsc test net. When I call any other function except the owner it gives the error "call to MasterChef.poolLength errored: Error: Internal JSON-RPC error. { "code": -32000, "message": "execution reverted" }".
I am using remix IDE for this and I can't figure out what is the problem. It is something related to gas cost but I don't get what's wrong.
This is the contract code
https://github.com/sushiswap/sushiswap/blob/master/contracts/MasterChef.sol

while deploying the contract I first deployed the SushiToken.sol on BSC and then copied its address to pass as the first arg to the constructor, second arg dev was my copied clipboard metamask address third was 1000000000000000000000 fourth was 0 and the fifth was 1000000000000000000000 for the MasterChef.sol constructor.

Comment: Please edit your question and state values that you passed into the constructor when deploying. It's possible that the error is caused by misconfiguration (passed in the constructor values).

Comment: @PetrHejda I have modified the statement

Comment: what is the dev address the second arg?